# Issue with removing a node

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm working on a link list and not currently able to remove a speficic node by a key value. I ask a helper at my school and he is not sure why it isn't working.(There is also a lot of try-catches for another issue I apologize for how gross it looks)

Here is my remove method:

```
public void remove(int key) throws Exception {
        Node tmp = first;
        Node pred = first;

        while (tmp != null) {
            if (tmp.keyValue == key) {
                pred = tmp;
                tmp = tmp.next;

            } else {
                tmp = tmp.next;
            }

        }
```

Here is my main method creaing the list and trying to remove it and print it:

```
OrderedLinkedList oLL3 = new OrderedLinkedList();
        try {
            oLL3.insert("Should be removed", 5);
            oLL3.insert("Shouldn't be removed 2nd", 15);
            oLL3.insert("Shouldn't be removed", 10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: Two nodes with the same key value and the newest one won't be stored.");
        }
        try {
            oLL3.remove(5);
        } catch (Exception r) {
            System.out.println("Error:No nod with the key value to be removed");
        }
        System.out.print("toString test removing node: \n" + oLL3.toString());

        System.out.println("Number of nodes in the List:" + oLL3.listCount());


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `remove` method is only assigning to local variables. That is not going to affect the state in your linked list. Assuming that the head of your list is the node held by the field `first`, you need to assign to either `first` or to the `.next` field in another node.

To remove the first node, you can do:

```
first = first.next;
```

To remove the node after node `prev`, you can do:

```
prev.next = prev.next.next;
```

(null-checking where appropriate)

Comment: My tmp and pred Node variables are assigned to first in the remove method. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: They are local variables. Assigning to them does not affect anything outside the method they belong to.

Comment: So you're saying instead of assigning first to something local in the  method, I should assign first to something that isn't a local variable? (I also just am not allowed to creat any member variables besides first.)

Comment: What you are doing is setting something to `first`. What you are not doing is setting `first` to anything else.

Comment: So if i just change the node to a diffrent node in the list I would be able to remove with my current code? The tmp(current) and pred(predecessor) are set to first which IS a member variable.

Comment: If you set a local variable to `first`, and then you set the variable to something else, it does not affect `first`.

Comment: Ok so I shoudln't set pred = to tmp than? After that I should pred to tmp.next so it will skip the node that contains first will be set so a different node skipping it correct?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Try writing some code and see if you can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

In this code shown you are deleting the first node of the linked list, and to delete the first node you need to point the "head" (or whatever the name of your head node is) to the second node, i.e.

```
head = head.next;
```